Failed to Upload a FIle to One Drive
I am trying to upload a file to One Drive and I keep on getting this error. The Folder is being created but the file was not uploaded.
I/flutter (13726): # Body: {"error":{"code":"unauthenticated","message":"Unauthenticated"}}

Here's the function:
Future<void> _uploadCsvToOneDrive(
    OneDrive onedrive, BuildContext context) async {

  const str = "Hello, World!";
  var data = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(str));
  try {
    print('Attempting to upload CSV file to OneDrive...');
    final success = await onedrive.push(data, "/Folder/data.txt");

    if (!success) {
      if (context.mounted) {
        informationSnackBar(
            context, Icons.warning, "Failed to upload CSV file to OneDrive.");
      }
    } else {
      if (context.mounted) {
        informationSnackBar(
            context, Icons.warning, "CSV file uploaded successfully.");
      }
    }
  } catch (e, stackTrace) {
    print('Error during upload: $e');
    print('Stack trace: $stackTrace');
  }
}

